# Alphabetical Checkbox input type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have a form containing checkboxes, however the text are not in alphabetical order. I have seen many examples for lists, not many for checkbox. http://jsfiddle.net/fG9qm/

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> Bee
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" > Apple
</form>
```

I managed to take a snippet of an example, however, if I try to change the value of the input the checkbox moves without the text - how can I solve this?

```
var $els = $('input');

var $sorted = $($els.toArray().sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.value > b.value;
}));

$els.each(function(i) {
    $(this).after($sorted.eq(i));
});
```

Also, is there a way to use to text instead of the value e.g.

```
return a.input.text > b.input.text
```

Any examples or help will be appreciated - thanks

Comment: how are these form inputs being added to the HTML, PHP, RUBY, by hand?  I would sort these that way personally

Comment: I'm using ruby for create the form inputs at the moment... but just thought this would be easier to explain

Comment: My point is that if you are pulling these from a database, sort them before you write the inputs themselves.  Otherwise you are creating a DOM and then re-ordering it, it just seems like unnecessary overhead.  If you need to do it after the fact, because of some user interaction that's a different story.  You need to wrap the labels in <label> tags and wrap the input in the label if you want them to stay together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap those textnodes in a label:

```
<form id="prac">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" /> Apple</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" /> ABear</label>
</form>
```

Then sort the labels

```
var myform = $('#prac'),
    els    = $('label', myform).get(),
    sorted = els.sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(a).text().toUpperCase()
                   .localeCompare( $(b).text().toUpperCase() );
});

$.each(sorted, function(idx, itm) { 
     myform.append(itm); 
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fG9qm/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the inputs and their respective labels in containers to facilitate sorting.

```
<form>
    <div class="field-item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="vehicle-bike" value="Bike" />
        <label for="vehicle-bike">Bee</label>
    </div>
    <div class="field-item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="vehicle-car" value="Car" />
        <label for="vehicle-car">Apple</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then just adjust your sorting code to sort those containers based on the labels.

```
var $els = $('.field-item');

var $sorted = $($els.toArray().sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).find('label').text() > $(b).find('label').text()
}));

$els.each(function(i) {
    $(this).after($sorted.eq(i));
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JLLp3/1/)**