# Checkbox display content without using HTML and CSS only (no JS)

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm setting up checkbox in a side navigation fashion in my html pages, I want the check box to display content upon selection. Example: Choose checkbox 1,2 display content only of that, No checkbox selected display all content.. How can i do this without Jquery/javascript. I want my webpage to maintain same functionality even if Javascript in browser is disabled. Can i do this by including w3.css as these styles are responsive without involving bootstrap

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show hide divs on click in HTML and CSS without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170781/show-hide-divs-on-click-in-html-and-css-without-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code has `id` for different `checkbox` and for there `contents` , onclick of any `checkbox`that content will be display:

```css
#content {
  display: none;
}

#show:checked ~ #content {
  display: block;
 }
  
#content1 {
  display: none;
}

#show1:checked ~ #content1 {
  display: block;
  }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="show">
<label for="show">check1</label>|
<input type="checkbox"id="show1">
<label for="show1">check2</label>


<span id="content">jvdkvdkvjdl</span>

 

<span id="content1">dkjvvhjvhkjdklhdlvk</span>
```

Comment: Although you have given input type="checkbox" why doesn't it show the checkbox to tick or untick?

Comment: Because i have given `display:none` to both checkboxes, See updated code i have change it .

Comment: Oh, Yes got that. Is it possible to sort the checkboxes alphabetically? If suppose it check1 and alphacheck 1. I want alphacheck1 to be displayed first?

Comment: Yes it is possible ,check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670153/alphabetical-checkbox-input-type) out .

Comment: No, I meant without JS

Comment: The usage of span doesn't work when I Place the checkboxes vertically. Why is it so?

Comment: can you elaborate it or try to post new question .

Comment: No I meant, the solution you gave me was having the checkboxes in a horizontal diasplay likke Chekbox1 | Checkbox2 but when I try to do the same vertically it doesn't work like
Checkbox1
Checkbox2

Comment: it is working i have recheck at my side it worked , can you should your code ?

Comment: It worked for me as well.. Thank you for your on-time response and great solution

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to learn the ":checked" selector. Here is a simple example.

HTML

```
<label for="trigger">Toggle box</label>
<div>
    OTHER HTML CONTENT
</div>
<input id="trigger" type="checkbox">
<div class="box">
  SHOW / HIDE BOX
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  display: none;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

#trigger {
  display: none;
}

#trigger:checked + .box {
  display: block;
}
```

As you can see the ":checked" selector can show or hide the DIV block. 
Here is an [interesting article](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/17/css-click-events/) on this topic.